# how to deploy and access loadbalancer kubernetes service on localhost/local machine using docker desktop k8s cluster?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, service, localhost, cluster-computing

unable to access the service deployed on local k8s cluster created using docker desktop.

```
#nginxsvc
#service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginxsvc
  labels:
    app: nginx-app
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx-app
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 8080 #service port
    targetPort: 8080 #container port
    protocols: TCP
```

```
#Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-app
    spec: 
      containers:
      - name: nginx-controller
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

```
NAME                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE   SELECTOR
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP          15m   <none>
service/nginxsvc     LoadBalancer   10.98.148.173   localhost     8080:32090/TCP   15m   app=nginx-app
```

tried accessing using `localhost:32090`

Answer (score 0):

Try on the `localhost:8080` You have to use the **nginxsvc**, **port**

The one you used **32090** is node port with this you have to use the `Node-IP:nodeport` to access.

Comment: I have studied somewhere that loadbalancer service deployed on localhost is converted into NodePort and nodeport is assigned as a service port,Is it true?

Comment: yes possible but depends which tool you are using.